# How to programmatically trigger Flip 3D on Windows?

Tags: windows

How do I programmatically trigger Flip 3D on Windows Vista and 7?

Is there an API for this and if so, what is it called and where can I find the relevant functions?  (I need a specific answer, eg a web link to the actual functions, not something generic like "Oh, it's in DirectX.")

On a related node, I have a Logitech mouse that has a "Document Flip" button that invokes Flip 3D (and then I can press up/down keys to page through the results.)  I am curious if they are using an official Windows API or if there is some low level hackery going on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to run a function from `dwmapi`

Sadly there is no proper funktion name only the ord-number `105`

You can try this by executing `%WinDir%\System32\rundll32.exe dwmapi #105` from Run-dialog or cmd.

**edit**
ive found out the Windows' API GetProcAddress Function accepts ord-numbers (the 105) as second parameter as well as proper name

> lpProcName [in] 
>   The function or variable name, or the function's ordinal value. If this parameter is an ordinal value, it must be in the low-order word; the high-order word must be zero.

so use this code

```
typedef vois (__cdecl *FlipProc)();
HINSTANCE hDwmApi = LoadLibrary(TEXT("dwmapi.dll"));
FlipProcAdd = (FlipProc) GetProcAddress(hDwmApi, (LPCSTR)105);
(FlipProcAdd)();
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks!  Have you ever used JNA by any chance?  How do you do it in JNA?  It does not seem immediately obvious because there is no function name, only a number, and I do not see an equivalent of GetProcAddress for JNA.  In either case, I accept this answer.  (I can figure out the JNA sooner or later if you don't know the answer.)