# filtering windows included in the undocumented dwmapi aero flip 3d function (flag-tab)

Tags: aero, dwm

greetings stackoverflow community!

you have taught me that [one way to invoke the undocumented Desktop Window Manager (DWM) / dwmapi flip3d function from a program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810580/how-to-programmatically-trigger-flip-3d-on-windows) is:

```
typedef void (__cdecl *FlipProc)();
HINSTANCE hDwmApi = LoadLibrary(TEXT("dwmapi.dll"));
FlipProcAdd = (FlipProc) GetProcAddress(hDwmApi, (LPCSTR)105);
(FlipProcAdd)();
```

my question is: is there any way to filter the list of application windows upon which the flip3d function operates?   what I want to do is filter, perhaps by window name or executable name, or other attributes, and invoke this function from a program, so that only the filtered results make it into the flip3d list.

or do I get to [write my own program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3848558/what-is-the-api-to-create-applications-like-flip3d) that mimics the flip3d function?

thanks,